# Confirmation on master detail page before exiting

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to ask for confirmation before exiting page but i tried every way i can find but nothing worked so far.

I have a master detail page as Application Main page.

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FaceApp.MainPageActive());
```

In that page Detail page is set like following.

```
Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(RecoveryForm)));
```

In Recovery form page i have following code

```
 protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                if (await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Are you sure you want to go back ?", "Yes", "No"))
                {
                    // Nothing works here. i tried many things including following
                    await Navigation.PopAsync();

                }
            });

        return true;
    }
```

Code runs successfully but nothing happens, if i remove code of running in Main thread application gets halted.

Comment: Did you create from project template or follow an example?

Comment: @Hassan From template.

Comment: I read that to use PopAsync you have to use PushAsync to navigate in the first place.

Comment: But where are you expecting to navigate back? To the previous page selected on the Main Page? Meaning, are you looking to change the Detail Page?

Comment: @HassanVoyeau i can't use that as its the main page of application and its master detail.

Comment: @pinedax if i don't override OnBackPressed then pressing back button closes the app or minimize as i can see it in active app list so i am trying to achieve same thing

Comment: @Ammad, If I override OnBackButtonPressed event in MasterDetailedPage.cs, and I can get confirmation when I click BackButton.